# Problems with "while" looping

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have to somehow do a function in which when I execute it I will be able to add all the divisors of a number, in the way shown below.

This is getting me crazy, I have been in the same problem for about an hour.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
  divisor = 1
  while divisor < n:
    if n%divisor==0:
      return divisor
      divisor = divisor + 1
    else:
      divisor = divisor + 1

print(sum_divisors(6)) # Should be 1+2+3=6
print(sum_divisors(12)) # Should be 1+2+3+4+6=16
```

Comment: Let me guess, the problem is *this code is unreachable*? (**you** should be the one to say it, not me).

Comment: I think it is a tradition you should also upvote the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search would lead you to answers with a lot of explanations: [sum of divisors in python](https://www.google.com/search?q=sum%20of%20divisors%20in%20python&rlz=1C1SQJL_enBD870BD870&oq=sum%20of%20divisors%20in%20python&aqs=chrome..69i57.4855j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

In case you think about some efficiency:

we need to check divisors till `sqrt` of a number

```
import math 
def sum_divisors(num) : 

    # Final result of summation of divisors 
    result = 0

    # find all divisors which divides 'num' 
    i = 2
    while i<= (math.sqrt(num)) : 

        # if 'i' is divisor of 'num' 
        if (num % i == 0) : 

            # if both divisors are same then 
            # add it only once else add both 
            if (i == (num / i)) : 
                result = result + i; 
            else : 
                result = result +  (i + num//i); 
        i = i + 1

    # Add 1 to the result as 1 is also  
    # a divisor 
    return (result + 1); 

print(sum_divisors(6))
print(sum_divisors(12))
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
def sum_divisors(n): 
    sum = 0
    z = 1

    while n > z:
        if n % z == 0:
            sum = sum + z
            z = z + 1
        else:
            z = z + 1
    # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
    return sum
```

Answer (score 2):

In your fonction, you return instantly after finding a divisor.
That's why your fonction doesnt work
Try to put each n%divisor == 0 in a list ans return it AT the end of the while.

Or try to print it directly.

Answer (score 1):

this here is weird:

```
if n%divisor==0:
      return divisor
      divisor = divisor + 1 //<= this is actually dead code, since is after the return statement...
```

on the other hand:

this here:

```
divisor = divisor + 1
```

works more like a counter but you are missing the accumulator...

you should do something like

```
accum = 0
while divisor < n:
    foo = n % divisor
    if foo == 0:
    accum = accum + divisor
```

Answer (score 1):

def sum_divisors(n):

```
total = [0]
divisors = 1
while divisors < n:
    if n % divisors == 0:
        result.append(divisors)
    else:
        pass
    divisors += 1
return sum(total)
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps provide context and makes your answer much more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple while loop to print the sum of all the divisors of a number. you should use an accumulator to increment the temp.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  accum = 1
  while n != 0 and accum < n:
    if n % accum == 0:
      sum += accum
    accum += 1
  return sum



print(sum_divisors(6)) # prints 6
print(sum_divisors(12)) # prints 16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  accum = 1
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
  while n != 0 and accum < n:
    if n % accum == 0:
      sum += accum
    accum += 1
  return sum

print(sum_divisors(0))
# 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```

Answer (score 0):

> There should be a if condition at line 5, so that the required result will be obtained for 0 also

```
if(num==0):
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sum = 0
  x = 1
  while n != 0 and x < n :
      
    if n % x == 0  :
      sum += x
    else:
      sum += 0
    x += 1    
  return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    x = 1
    a = 0
    while n!=0 and x<n:
        if n%x == 0:
        a = a + x
        x += 1  
    #Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
    return a

print(sum_divisors(0)) #0

print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1

print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18

print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my code(didn't clean it up but it works well) :

```py
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum = 0
    divisors = 1
    while divisors < n:
      if n == 0:
        return 0
      else:
        if n % divisors == 0:
           sum += divisors
           divisors += 1
        else:
           divisors += 1
           continue
    # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
    return sum

print(sum_divisors(0))
# 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```